# ElasticSearch : observer: timeout notification from cluster service

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a ElasticSearch Cluster with 3 Data Master Nodes, one dedicated Client Node  & a logstash sending events to Elasticsearch Cluster via the elasticsearch client node.

The Client is not able to connect to the cluster and seeing the below errors in log:-

```
[2015-10-24 00:18:29,657][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.create] [ESClient] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [1m], time since start [1m]
[2015-10-24 00:18:30,743][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.create] [ESClient] no known master node, scheduling a retry
```

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473687/elasticsearch-cluster-no-known-master-node-scheduling-a-retry) answer but it is not working for me. My Master-Data elastic search config looks like below:-

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: "ESMasterData1"
node.master: true
node.data: true
index.number_of_shards: 7
index.number_of_replicas: 1
bootstrap.mlockall: true
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["es-master3:9300", "kibana:9300", "es-master2:9300", "es-master1:9300"]
cloud.aws.access_key: AK
cloud.aws.secret_key: J0
```

ES Client Config looks like below:-

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: "ESClient"
node.master: false
node.data: false
index.number_of_shards: 7
index.number_of_replicas: 1
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["es-master1:9300", "es-master2:9300", "es-master3:9300", "kibana:9300"]
bootstrap.mlockall: true
cloud.aws.access_key: AK
cloud.aws.secret_key: J0
```

The nodes are having all the standard configuration like JVM Heap set to 30GB & mlockall set to true.

Logstash Output looks like below:

```
elasticsearch {
      index => "j-%{env}-%{app}-%{iver}-%{[@metadata][app_log_time]}"
      cluster => "elasticsearch"
      host => "kibana"
      port => "9300"
      protocol => "transport"
    }
```

Telnet is working fine from ES Client Node to ES Master-Data nodes on port 9300. Also all the three ES Master-Data nodes are able to talk to each other. I have also verified TCP & UDP is enabled between the client & data-master machine by using iperf.

I am using Elastic Search Version 1.7.1 on Debian 7

Can some one let me know what is going wrong or how can I debug this?

Comment: Are your three data/master nodes and the client node hosted on AWS by any chance?

Comment: No they are not hosted in AWS @val.