# Cannot setup Elasticsearch cluster (though following a previous SO answer)

Tags: elasticsearch, centos

By following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22165235/3134055), I set up my `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` as follows (almost equivalent to the linked answer):

Node 1 (192.168.136.6):

```
cluster.name: mycluster
node.name: "node1"
node.master: true
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.168.136.6"]
```

Node 2 (192.168.152.244):

```
cluster.name: mycluster
node.name: "node2"
node.master: false
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.168.136.6"]
```

and everything else is set to default, i.e. they're commented out.

By `curl http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true` on Node 1, I get:

```
...
"number_of_nodes" : 1,
"number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
...
```

so apparently Node 1&2 are not clustered. What am I missing?

Note: I'm using ES 2.3.4 on CentOS 6.5. At least ping from Node 2 to 1 and 1 to 2 works. I turned off iptables temporarily (because I want to make sure the firewall setting isn't causing the problem). I tried two VPS services and it still doesn't work (and so I removed "on Linode" from the title).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticserch Master not discoverd exception - Version 2.3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130943/elasticserch-master-not-discoverd-exception-version-2-3-0)

Comment: You've asked it in a different way, but the answer is the result of the same issue. ES 2.0+ only binds sockets to localhost by default. So, being on separate IPs, the two nodes cannot see each other.

Comment: Though I posted the answer by myself, your comment helped me finding the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I could solve the issue but it was actually a bit complicated. My servers (on Linode) only have the interface `eth0`, which is bound to the outer internet, and the alias `eth0:0` is bound to the private network. Thus, I had to set `network.host` to `_eth0:0_`, which, however, [does not work (maybe a bug)](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17473). Therefore, I set `network.host` to `_site_` instead, which seems to be practically converted to `_eth0:0_` in this case. Now I have a properly clustered ES.

`_global_` might also work but I hesitate to use it because I'm not sure if it's safe.