# How to configure two nodes to connect to same cluster in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 separate machines. Port 9200 is already taken by a separate elasticsearch running, so I specify 9201 as the http.port in the yml file. i set cluster.name: MyCluster.

When I start ./elasticsearch on machine 1 and machine 2, they are not connected, but each are single node master's.

What do I need to do so that they can connect to each other and be part of the same cluster?

I also set network.host: 0.0.0.0 so I know they can see each other. I am using 2.4.0 of Elastcisearch.

Comment: just see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821101/how-to-set-up-es-cluster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821101/how-to-set-up-es-cluster)

Answer (score 2):

In machine 1:

```
cluster.name: hello_world
network.host: "hostname_or_ip_1"
network.port: 9201
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["hostname_or_ip_2:9201"]
```

In machine 2:

```
cluster.name: hello_world
network.host: "hostname_or_ip_2"
network.port: 9201
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["hostname_or_ip_1:9201"]
```

- Both cluster name should be same
- `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` should point to correct machine
  address with port
- Make sure to restart elasticsearch node after editing config file

Answer (score 0):

Look at unicast discovery with host:port.  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html

You might also need to be explicit about the transport.tcp.port in your elasticsearch.yml:

`transport.tcp.port: 9301`

Comment: Is it possible to not use unicast when its not on the default port? I like it when you just specify the cluster name and it generally finds it. Unfortunately, its not working I think because there is already an instance running that I want this to not be sharing the same cluster name with.

Comment: I just tried only the transport.tcp.port: 9301, still starts up as separate masters.